# How can I fit the eye texture in the photo to the UV Sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

I'm trying this process, but when I pin the eye texture to the front, the tissue goes inside as if there was a black hole in the middle of the sphere. Actually, I don't know anything about UV Editing. Right now I'm just going to use it to shape the eye tissue into a sphere. I don't know exactly where I should click after the process in the picture. By the way, after creating the uv sphere, I rotated it on the X axis and added an eye material.

[image]

Comment: put your view in front of the eye in Orthographic view and unwrap with the Project From View option, it will also project the iris on the back but you should not care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to do it would be to put your view in front of the sphere in orthographic view and unwrap with the *Project from View* option:

[image]

Then in the *UV Editor* scale and move the UV until it fits:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Of course the iris will be projected on the back of the sphere as well. If it bothers you, you can correct in *Texture Paint* mode: Select the back part of the mesh, move its UV and put it over a blank background:

[image]

Now in *Texture Paint* mode, either use the *Clone* brush to pick a sample of the texture or use a white color to paint on the back:

[image]

Comment: It's working. Thanks.